# Getting error while installing other packages in R after installing Rtool40 packages

Tags: r, error-handling, r-package

I am facing problem installing any/other packages after I installed the package "Rtools40" in R version 4.0.2. Here is the error I get:

```
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.1/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.
```

I have tried deleting the hidden file of Rtools40 called "./Renviron" still it didn't work for me. Even reinstalled the whole package Rtools40 in my device but I am still getting same error while installing any other R packages like DESeq2.
Please help me to deal with this error.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: What version of R are you running? It looks like R 3.6.1. You should use the version of RTools that corresponds to the version of R you are running. So perhaps you should update your R to at least version 4.0.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick, Yes the version I a using is R 3.6.1 and I will definetly give it a try to update it. But now I want to use other packages and I am unable to install them after installing Rtools40. So I have uninstall Rtools40 and tried again to install other package in R but I am still getting the same error. What should I do to deal with this error while insatlling other tools.

Comment: Also my previously installed packages are not working.

Comment: Hey I reinstalled the new version of R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22). Then I tried to install the

> BiocManager::install("DESeq2")

Here is the error I got:

Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.2/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? Can you confirm you are on a 64-bit machine?

Comment: Yes, I am using windows 10 64-bit

Comment: Maybe check this out: https://community.rstudio.com/t/stat-package-will-not-load-after-installing-rtools/63265/11. Do you have an `.Reviron` file?

Comment: I did put the location of the Rtools make utilities on the PATH in R using:         writeLines('PATH="${RTOOLS40_HOME}\\usr\\bin;${PATH}"', con = "~/.Renviron") ,                                                                                           Sys.which("make"),                                                                                                             
install.packages("jsonlite", type = "source").    I successfully installed these packages but when I tried to locate the ./Renviron hidden file in the file explorer I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: My R is still not working, I neither can use any of my previously installed pacakges nor can install new pacakge. The error keep saying "LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found."